# Where do the Sec- headers get their name?

Tags: http, request, http-headers

Most modern browsers send a variety of `Sec-` headers in their requests, like `Sec-Fetch-Site` and `Sec-Fetch-Dest`. I did some searching and checked the spec, but I couldn't find what "Sec" means.

I'm not sure if this is the right site to ask on